# Harmony Lines for Pentatonic Melodies

Tags: harmony, scales

I found this great video on harmonizing pentatonic melodies. By harmonize in the case I mean creating second lines to go with a melody, rather than finding a suitable chord progression.

The premise seems to be that we harmonize each note with its 5th, except for when the 5th is not in the pentatonic scale, in which case we use the 4th.

that would mean for a D Minor pentatonic Scale we would have the following mapping:

D -> A
F -> C
G -> D
A -> D
C -> G

In the video he's using a different mode of the pentatonic scale, but I've extrapolated the principle for the minor pentatonic. Also, in case it's relevant, I often need to write the second part higher than the original line, rather than lower, for example if the music is for 2 descant recorders and the original melody is in the lower range.

So that's one schema. However, I'm sure there are many other ways to harmonize the notes of a minor pentatonic scale. I can see two main categories of how this might be approached:

1. Only use notes from the original pentatonic scale, but with a different mapping than the one shown above, perhaps not always fixed.
2. Allow the use of notes from one of the "parent" scales, which would consist of the 4 combinations of "missing" 2nd and 6th degree (F Major / D Aeolian, Bb Major / D Phrygian, C Major / D Dorian, and D Cappadocian / C melodic minor ascending)

In category 2, would it for example make sense to simply play 3rds above each degree, from a chosen implicit parent scale? I suspect that in some cases the 3rd would sound good for some notes but not others.

I expect the ear should be the ultimate judge of how best to go about this process, but it would be good to hear suggestions as to systematic approaches I could use.

Comment: I've been meaning to sit down and transcribe the guitar/guitar/keyboard trio from Frank Zappa's "City of tiny lights", as an example of good pentatonic harmony. https://youtu.be/QH-rR42jeI0?t=246

Comment: You can do either.  The end result will sound different.  Try them both.  Which do you prefer?

Comment: “Suggestions for systematic approaches” is a bit of a broad ask. Can you narrow this down to a question that has a single answer? One difficulty with this kind of question is there are too many ways to harmonize a melody, and the different ways have different sounds, all of which are subjectively “good” or “bad” depending on genre, context, etc. We can’t really tell you how to harmonize anything, but we can answer technical questions about specific ways to harmonize.

Comment: 'Cappadocian' is a new one on me. Google didn't help.

Comment: @Tim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorian_%E2%99%AD2_scale It's a real thing, apparently....

Comment: When I write heavy metal guitar riffs, I'm often using power chords (just root and perfect 5th).  In a diatonic mode, there's always one scale degree that has a diminished 5th but I play the perfect 5th.  I use a lot of exotic scales too and some of them have numerous scale degrees which don't have a perfect 5th above them, but I still just play the power chord.  When using power chords melodically, the 2 notes blend into one composite sound.  The foreign note is not heard as an accidental because you're not consciously hearing it at all.

Comment: Brilliant. So perfect fifths above at all times. Probably quite a medieval vibe, and breaks some "rules" but I like it.